# How do I append this jquery code to the end of the document?

Tags: jquery, append

I need to append the following jquery to the bottom of the document.. Just before the closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags.. How can I do this?

```
$(function(){
    $("#AttachmentFile").change(function(){
        $("#ufo-field-id-948").val($(this).val())
        var string = $("#ufo-field-id-948").val();
        var new_string = string.replace('C:\\fakepath\\', '');
        $("#ufo-field-id-948").val(new_string); 
    });
});
```

Here is the code it needs to be added to, and then appended below the first append

```
        _createInput: function(){

        var self = this;



        var input = document.createElement("input");

        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');

        input.setAttribute('name', this._settings.name);

        input.setAttribute('id', 'AttachmentFile');
        if(this._settings.multiple) input.setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple');



        addStyles(input, {

            'position' : 'absolute',

            'right' : 0,

            'margin' : 0,

            'padding' : 0,

            'fontSize' : '480px',

            'fontFamily' : 'sans-serif',

            'cursor' : 'pointer'

        });



        var div = document.createElement("div");

        addStyles(div, {

            'display' : 'block',

            'position' : 'absolute',

            'overflow' : 'hidden',

            'margin' : 0,

            'padding' : 0,

            'opacity' : 0,

            'direction' : 'ltr',

            'zIndex': 2147483583

        });



        if ( div.style.opacity !== "0") {

            if (typeof(div.filters) == 'undefined'){

                throw new Error('Opacity not supported by the browser');

            }

            div.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";

        }



        addEvent(input, 'change', function(){



            if ( ! input || input.value === ''){

                return;

            }



            var file = fileFromPath(input.value);



            if (false === self._settings.onChange.call(self, file, getExt(file))){

                self._clearInput();

                return;

            }



            if (self._settings.autoSubmit) {

                self.submit();

            }

        });



        addEvent(input, 'mouseover', function(){

            addClass(self._button, self._settings.hoverClass);

        });



        addEvent(input, 'mouseout', function(){

            removeClass(self._button, self._settings.hoverClass);

            removeClass(self._button, self._settings.focusClass);



            if (input.parentNode) {

                input.parentNode.style.visibility = 'hidden';

            }

        });



        addEvent(input, 'focus', function(){

            addClass(self._button, self._settings.focusClass);

        });



        addEvent(input, 'blur', function(){

            removeClass(self._button, self._settings.focusClass);

        });



    div.appendChild(input);

        document.body.appendChild(div);



        this._input = input;

    },
```

Comment: How do you want to append it?  Are you wanting to use javascript to append it, html, .... ?

Comment: Append the jQuery? You mean place it between script tags at the bottom of the page?

Comment: 1. Open up a text editor.  2. Copy & Paste.  3. ???? 4. Profit.

Comment: Sounds like you're pretty inexperienced with this stuff.  Have you tried what the other commenters are suggestion? If its not working, have you included jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to surround it with script tags. Then put it where you need to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#AttachmentFile").change(function(){
            $("#ufo-field-id-948").val($(this).val())
            var string = $("#ufo-field-id-948").val();
            var new_string = string.replace('C:\\fakepath\\', '');
            $("#ufo-field-id-948").val(new_string); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There should be a `</script>` at the end which isn't showing up... Not sure why...

Comment: U only have 3 spaces before it, add one

Comment: If you haven't included jquery, you can add this line directly above that code: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify... I am using this piece of code to grab the value from a text field, and displaying it in another one. However, part of the code I am using appends the field "AttachmentFile" to the bottom of the document, making this code not work. So I need to append this below the other already appended code.. Gosh I hope this makes sense, lol